# Growth models in R - predictions - Bayesian or not Bayesian?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, bayesian, growth-model

This is my first question here.
I am currently working on (nonlinear) growth models using the `FSA` package in `R`. I compared several models. According to AIC the logistic model performed best.
Now I'd like to predict age from size. First I thought that I simply could solve the equation for age using the parameters obtained with the growth models - but then there arise problems with logs of negative arguments for large specimens since Linf is the mean asymptotic length -> error.

Through an internet search I found this article (http://www.bioone.org/doi/10.2981/wlb.00185) where the authors follow a similar path but then use a Bayesian approach to predict age from (eye lens) weight - confirming my doubts.
Now I need your advice:

1) Am I correct that my first idea is not working? Or what am I doing wrong?

2) If so - I'd be grateful for advise how to get started with Bayesian methods. This is a completely new field for me.

Here is my R code and data:

```
require(FSA)
age <- c(15,17,22,23,23,24,24,24,25,25,27,27,31,31,35,35,39,39,43,43,47,47,55,
55,63,63,75,75,334,334,334,334,334)
size <- c(13.8,16.4,17.7,20.5,17.6,20.0,21.6,20.9,23.0,25.0,24.9,27.0,27.0,25.3,
26.4,29.6,26.5,30.8,28.7,30.6,29.9,32.3,30.0,31.7,29.8,33.9,29.0,31.8,
32.0,30.0,31.4,35.0,35.4)
data <- data.frame(age,size)

# Logistic model
( log <- logisticFuns() )
fit.L <- nls(size~log(age,Linf,gninf,ti),data=data,
start=list(Linf=31,gninf=.1,ti=17))
summary(fit.L)
```

The model in FSA is:

size = $\frac{Linf}{1 + e^{(-gninf * (age - ti)))}}$

with Linf = mean assymptotic length; gninf = instantaneous growth rate at negative infinity; ti = age at inflection point

which I solved to:
age = ti + $\frac{log(Linf/size)-1}{-gninf}$